# How to show text on a SVG path

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, d3.js

So I have points on my SVG map and now I would like to **show text** next to them. This is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/g25ceyr1/2/) with 2 points and showing their ID text. But as you can see there is no text somehow.

```
var featureCollection = topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.testtest);

lines.append("g")
  .attr("id", "lines")
  .selectAll("path")
  .data(featureCollection.features)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", path)
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "nodetext")
  .attr("x", 22)
  .attr("y", 4)
  .text(function (d) {
      return d.properties.id;
  });
```

And I checked it with some other text beside example I already have [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/d2gjxy7n/).  It's working in the same way.

So does it not work with pathes? Could that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @liamness says, your text can't be a child of `path` but needs to be a sibling.   Your problem goes a little further, though, since you are using a path and you can't group and position the element conventionally.  There is where [path.centroid](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#path_centroid) comes in handy.  It allows you to find the center of you path and position your text there:

```
var e = lines.append("g")
    .attr("id", "lines")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(featureCollection.features)
    .enter(); // save enter selection

e.append("path") // add path as child of lines g
    .attr("d", path); 

e.append("text") // add text as child of lines g, sibling of path
    .attr("class", "nodetext")
    .attr('x', function(d,i){
        return path.centroid(d)[0]; // horizontal center of path
    })
    .attr('y', function(d,i){
       return path.centroid(d)[1] + 13; // vertical center of path
    })
    .attr('text-anchor','middle')
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.properties.id;
    });
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g25ceyr1/3/).

Comment: Wow this works instantly, perfectly and is really straigthforward. Awesome. Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A 'text' element can't be a child of a 'path' element, it should be a sibling. Group them if they are related and need to be positioned accordingly.

Comment: Could you give me an example about how to change the svg code? Or just how the strcture should be? I'm not completely sure how to solve it.