# Add caption to d3 line element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

What I'm running now is showing a root node and bunch of nodes connected to it via d3 `line` element. I'd like to add a caption to the line, since I have it defined and can freely grab it from `d.label` (in the nodes section in JSON). I'm using the following code:

```
var width = 500,
    height = 500;
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .charge(-800)

    .linkDistance(d => d.distance)

    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("#target").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("class", "mainsvg");
var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");


d3.json("test.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();


  link = link.data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link");


  node = node.data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("a")      
    node.append("g")
      .attr("class", "node");    

    node.append("circle")
      .attr("class", "circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r })
      .attr("fill", function(d) { return d.color })
      .attr("stroke", function(d){ return d.color });

});

function tick() {

  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });
  svg.selectAll(".circle").attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  svg.selectAll(".text").attr("x", function(d) { return d.x+d.xoffs; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y+d.yoffs; });

}
```

Now I've tried using normal `<text>` elements appended to the `edgepath` in this fashion:

```
var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr({'d': function(d) {return 'M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y},
               'class':'edgepath',
               'fill-opacity':0,
               'stroke-opacity':0,
               'fill':'blue',
               'stroke':'red',
               'id':function(d,i) {return 'edgepath'+i}})
        .style("pointer-events", "none");
var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .attr({'class':'edgelabel',
               'id':function(d,i){return 'edgelabel'+i},
               'dx':80,
               'dy':10,
               'font-size':10,
               'fill':'black'});

edgelabels.append('textPath')
        .attr('xlink:href',function(d,i) {return '#edgepath'+i})
        .style("pointer-events", "none")
        .text(function(d){return d.label});
```

However, the results I get are weird to say at best. Some labels are too close together, some are missing, but all of them are in the wrong place. How would I move them where they should be? To keep something in mind, I'm looking for a simple way to add caption to the paths I already have drawn out, nothing else. So the method I tried may have been too much, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `dx` in your `edgelabels`, that's always the same:

```
'dx': 80,
```

Assuming that you're using the code with the link distance (as in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353614/controling-line-length-d3-js)), the solution is simple:

```
'dx':function(d){return d.distance/2},
```

Check the demo:

```js
var nodes = [{
    name: "a"
}, {
    name: "b"
}, {
    name: "c"
}, {
    name: "d"
}, {
    name: "e"
}, {
    name: "f"
}];

var links = [{
    source: 1,
    target: 0,
    distance: 80,
    label: "foo"
}, {
    source: 2,
    target: 0,
    distance: 40,
    label: "bar"
}, {
    source: 3,
    target: 0,
    distance: 180,
    label: "baz"
}, {
    source: 4,
    target: 0,
    distance: 80,
    label: "foobar"
}, {
    source: 5,
    target: 0,
    distance: 90,
    label: "foobaz"
}]

var width = 400
height = 300;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(d => d.distance)
    .charge(-1000)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("class", "link");

var edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr({
        'd': function(d) {
            return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y
        },
        'class': 'edgepath',
        'fill-opacity': 0,
        'stroke-opacity': 0,
        'fill': 'blue',
        'stroke': 'red',
        'id': function(d, i) {
            return 'edgepath' + i
        }
    })
    .style("pointer-events", "none");

var edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr({
        'class': 'edgelabel',
        'id': function(d, i) {
            return 'edgelabel' + i
        },
        'dx': function(d) {
            return d.distance / 2
        },
        'dy': 10,
        'font-size': 12,
        'fill': 'black'
    });

edgelabels.append('textPath')
    .attr('xlink:href', function(d, i) {
        return '#edgepath' + i
    })
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.label
    });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", (d, i) => i ? 10 : 16)
    .style("fill", (d, i) => i ? "teal" : "brown");

function tick() {



    link.attr("x1", function(d) {
            return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

    edgepaths.attr('d', function(d) {
        var path = 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
        return path
    });



}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's exactly right. I also didn't include paths/labels in the tick update, which made it super-messed up. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`text` cannot be a child of `path` [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29062764/how-to-show-text-on-a-svg-path) `path` is not a container... [per SVG spec.](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermContainerElement)

best practice would be to first append `g` elements to your SVG as containers for the bound data, then append the `path` and `text` elements to the `g` so that they are siblings. Then you have complete control over relative positioning, etc.

Comment: I do have a g container elements that holds my `circle` and `text` at the moment, but the `line` element is outside of the container. Also, no matter how I try to append path and use the `centroid`, it doesn't work. I'm getting errors, I've added the path/text right after `node.append("g")` and it's giving me: `path.centroid is not a function`

Comment: Like I got `<a>` element as container, so I can put text element there easy, but getting a path with values from the `line`, which i assume is what they, not sure I understand how